# Detect a rectangle with wider sides (tram signal)

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm trying to write simple program to detect tram signal. Problem with this signal is that, it's not straight rectangle but it's look like this:

[image: tram signal]

I tried to detect it but sometime's it's working sometimes not.
Main problem with this is shape of this signal.
For approximation I'm using:

```
CvInvoke.ApproxPolyDP(cannyCounturs[i], approx, CvInvoke.ArcLength(cannyCounturs[i], true) * 0.05, true);
```

it's look like problem is here, where program tries to approximate curves but in this shape there are too many for it to get is as rectangle (as i understand).
Is there a way to detect this signal correctly?

Here is screenshot how it's look like:

[image: detection]